# Update text box value when the date is changed

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

I have saved these details in database and binded to grid view

whenever the start date is crossed one month i want to update payment value to double 
like that i want to update payment for 3 months(example for 3 months 5000+5000+5000=15000 )

this is my code

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"server=SYS8\SQLSERVER2008DE;database=Naresh;Integrated Security=true");
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from ValueUpdate", con);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        GridView1.DataSource = ds;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
    protected void txtStartDate_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string inputString = txtStartDate.Text;
        DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(inputString, "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        dt = dt.AddMonths(Convert.ToInt32(ddlmonths.SelectedItem.ToString()));
        txtEndDate.Text = dt.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");

    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        con.Open();

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into ValueUpdate (NoOfMonths,StartDate,EndDate,Payment) values('" + ddlmonths.SelectedItem + "','" + txtStartDate.Text + "','" + txtEndDate.Text + "','" + txtMonthlyPay.Text + "')", con);

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 0):

How will you verify that start date has crossed one month? What will be base date for this?